# GOOGLE ERROR: In order to select an item from your online storage, please sign in

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am getting an error of

> "In order to select an item from your online storage, please sign in.".

I found a suggestion to deal with this situation was to Disable Block third-party cookies from chrome browser. And the other was to Allow [*.]google.com but none of this worked.

And I am using Google Drive in my own project through API. And by opening that popup I am getting this error.

Any Solution?[image: Here is the image too to check]

Comment: Have you tried logging in?  You cant access private data without permission.    Please include your code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried Signing In but still doesn't work. And I am using angular-google-picker if you want to see the code.

Comment: If signing in doesn't work, then your implementation is not properly handling the access tokens you are receiving. You supply no code, so we can't help you - we can only vote to close because you ask "why isn't this working" and provide no context or MCVE.

Comment: Bro this ain't an error of my code. This issue is of Google and this was in working condition but before some days I am getting this issue. It is working if I run my code in localhost but when it is deployed on server then it is not working.

Comment: Edit your question to include context, relevant code, research, and relevant links. Otherwise it looks like a poorly researched, poorly asked question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got a solution and worked for me. Settings in Chrome then Content Settings and Uncheck Block third-party cookies and site data.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know why he closed this question, in some case updating chrome setting doesn't work. Anyone still faces the problem, try this:
function onAuthApiLoad(){gapi.auth2.init({client_id:clientId}).then(function(n){n.signIn({scope:scope}).then(function(n){handleAuthResult(n.getAuthResponse())})})}function handleAuthResult(n){n&&!n.error&&(token=n.access_token,createPicker())}function onApiLoad(){null===picker&&null!==developerKey&&null!==clientId&&null!==scope&&(gapi.load("picker",null),gapi.load("auth2",onAuthApiLoad))}