# google picker to drive files with access token from backend results in please sign in error

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-picker

i need create google picker with accsess token fro beack-end (node js)

I am getting this error message:

> "Google In order to select an item from your online storage, please sign in. Sign in"

from nodeJs i get successful access token by refresh token like this:

```
let cookies = req.headers['authorization']
let getCookies = JSON.parse(cookies)
let oauth2Client = getOAuthClient()
oauth2Client.setCredentials(getCookies)
return oauth2Client.credentials.access_token
```

on client side(react)

```
//oauthToken= acsess token from server
  const picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                             .addView(view)
                             .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                             .setCallback(this.props.onChange);
```

fetch to get access token and send it to create picker function.

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4002/driveApi`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          authorization: TokenToString
        }
      })
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          this.createPicker(response.data)
       
        })
```

create picker function:

```
  createPicker (oauthToken) {
    //this.props.onAuthenticate(oauthToken)

    if (this.props.createPicker) {
      return this.props.createPicker(window.google, oauthToken)
    }
    
    const googleViewId = window.google.picker.ViewId['DOCS']
    const view = new window.google.picker.View(googleViewId)

    if (this.props.mimeTypes) {
      view.setMimeTypes(this.props.mimeTypes.join(','))
    }
    if (this.props.query) {
      view.setQuery(this.props.query)
    }

    if (!view) {
      throw new Error("Can't find view by viewId")
    }

    const picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
      .addView("DOCS")
      .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
      .setCallback(this.props.onChange)

    if (this.props.origin) {
      picker.setOrigin(this.props.origin)
    }

    if (this.props.navHidden) {
      picker.enableFeature(window.google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
    }

    if (this.props.multiselect) {
      picker.enableFeature(window.google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
    }

    picker.build().setVisible(true)
  }
```

add build credentials code:

````
function getOAuthClient () {
 return new OAuth2(ClientId, ClientSecret, RedirectionUrl)
}

function getAuthUrl () {
 var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient()
 var scopes =
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
 var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
   access_type: 'offline',
   scope: scopes
 })
 return url
}```
````

Comment: Do you have an error? whats the issue with what you have now?

Comment: yes, i get this error: "Google
In order to select an item from your online storage, please sign in.
Sign in"
thanks.....

Comment: Your authorization is not working you might want to look at this https://developers.google.com/picker/docs#example

Comment: i do authorizion on sever-side, i get acsess token by refresh token. on client i whant just creat a picker to drive fiels

Comment: Does this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276607/4243927 help you?

Comment: thanks a lot but no, its not my problam:(
to ather google api i success get data(like people api, calander api) with same access token

Comment: YOu can use the same access token assuming that you requested both a calendar scope and a profile scope when authorizing your user.   Im not seeing anything about which scopes you have authorized with.

Comment: i use with same accsess token, so that i know my problam its on google picker.you have any idea?

Comment: Please share the code where you build your credentials with which scopes

Comment: i add o the question. thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The issue is likely because of cookies, try clearing the cookies.